# Limit involving complicated integral

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} e^{x(\cos t-1)}\cos t\ dt$$
I attempted to work out the integral part, but it did not work well because of the existence of the e part. So whether there is a better and more convient way to calculate this limit.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

[Laplace's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) provides a relatively simple result.  Here, one sees that the integral is dominated by the contribution in a small neighborhood about $t=0$.  In this neighborhood, $1-\cos{t} \sim t^2/2$.  The neighborhood is thus defined by $0 \lt x t^2/2 \lt \epsilon \implies 0 \lt t \lt \sqrt{2 \epsilon/x}$.  Because the integral contributions outside this neighborhood are exponentially small, we may simply approximate the integral with

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-x t^2/2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 x}}$$

Note that we are OK with replacing the cosine outside the exponential by $1$ because, to this order, it doesn't contribute.  The limit you seek is thus $\sqrt{\pi/2}$.

**ADDENDUM**

Just for laughs, let's verify numerically that this is in fact the correct leading asymptotic behavior.  Here are a few Mathematica commands and output:

---

Integral to be evaluated. 
$$f(\text{x$\_$})\text{:=}\text{NIntegrate}\left[\cos (t) \exp (-x (1-\cos (t))),\left\{t,0,\frac{\pi }{4}\right\}\right]$$

Log-Log plot of the integral superimposed with its leading asymptotic behavior:
$$\text{Plot}\left[\left\{\log _{10}\left(f\left(10^x\right)\right),\log _{10}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)-\frac{x}{2}\right\},\{x,0,4\}\right]$$

[image]

---

Log-Log plot of difference between integral and leading asymptotic behavior.  Note the slope is $-3/2$, the exponent of the next order behavior:

$$\text{Plot}\left[\log _{10}\left(\left| f\left(10^x\right)-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2\ 10^x}}\right| \right),\{x,2,4\}\right]$$

[image]

Comment: @TooOldForMath: it is of course not oscillatory - that's the case Laplace's Method deals with.  Your assertion is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, as so often again I must admit that I cannot read :).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the argument of Ron Gordon, which provides a very concise proof.

Another way : Consider the same integral, but with the upper boundary $= pi/2$ instead of $pi/4$. The limit is the same (same argument already given by Ron Gordon). The advantage is that a closed form is known for the integral. Then, the limit for $x$ can be directly derived :

$$\sqrt x\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{x(\cos (t)-1)}\cos(t)dt=\sqrt x\dfrac\pi2e^{-x}\big(I_1(x)+L_{-1}(x)\big).$$
$I_1(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. 
 $L_{-1}(x)$ is the modified Struve function. 
 For $x\rightarrow\infty:$ the functions $I_1(x)$ and $L_{-1}(x)$ are both equivalent to: $$e^x\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi x}}+O\left(\dfrac1{x^{3/2}}\right)\right).$$ As a consequence: $$\sqrt x\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{x(\cos (t)-1)}\cos(t)dt
\approx \sqrt x \dfrac\pi2e^{-x}\left(2e^x\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi x}}+O\left(\dfrac1{x^{3/2}}\right)\right)\right) \\ \ \\
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sqrt x\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{x(\cos (t)-1)}\cos(t)dt=\sqrt{\dfrac\pi2}.$$

Corrected : There was a mistake in the calculus of the asymptotic series.

Comment: JJacquelin: very astute observation, but perhaps you would do well to consider how those asymptotic expressions were derived.

Comment: Ron Gordon : This is a very pertinent point. Any answer is based on older studies and results previously published sometimes centuries ago. For example, it should be of interest to consider how was setteled the Laplace method which is so convenient to apply in the present case.